# Will any model of Seagate 1 TB Barracuda SATA Internal HDD be compatible with Dell T110 PowerEdge Compact Tower Server?

Tags: hard-drive, dell-poweredge

We have a [Dell T110 PowerEdge Compact Tower Server](http://www.dell.com/in/business/p/poweredge-t110-2/pd). One of its internal hard disks (Model No.  ST31000528AS, Seagate 1 TB Barracuda ) has developed bad sectors. We plan to replace it.

In general, would any other Seagate internal 1 TB  Barracuda SATA HDD be compatible with the server ? For example, the model : ST1000DM010 . Are there any flipsides in putting a "not recommended" HDD ? Are all SATA Seagate Barracuda 1 TB HDDs the same ?

If it helps, Context for the question (not the main question here):

This had happened to another identical server two years back and the price of the replacement HDD of identical model specification ST31000528AS was reasonable. However, now the price of the identical model seems to have tripled on Amazon India. (From USD 44/INR 3800 to USD 178/INR 12000).

The server is 7 years old, no warranty is applicable. Nor am I looking for a Dell warranty for the new HDD.

RAID is disabled.

Comment: I think, the BIOS of this server isn't support 4K/512e disks.

Comment: How can I know this for sure, from the server BIOS  and also the specifications of the cheaper HDD model I am planning to buy ? Where/what should I look for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this server can support 4Kn or 512e SATA disks (Read about [Advanced format on WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)). I looked for a 512e disk in BIOS update release notes, but didn't found anything. You can test BIOS by any 512e disk. If you'll see this disk in BIOS menu then you can use it.

To use disks with  **Advanced format** 4Kn or 512e you must change SATA port to AHCI mode and enable UEFI in BIOS. Also the operation system on your server must support such HDD. In addition: **All partitions on such HDD must be aligned to 4Kb sectors**.

The disk model ST1000DM010 has 4096 bytes per sector (4K/512e).

Another way - use 512n (512 bytes per sector native) disks, by example: ST1000NM0008.